# TFS Source Control Uncompressed Build

Tags: version-control, build, tfs

Is there a way to create a "build" but not actually compile the output of the site? Bascially I want to push the files live from the source control in TFS to the final IIS folder destination.

I have used CopyDirectory on my other project builds, but that requires a BuildDetail.DropLocation (compiled Build). Maybe there is another option for the CopyDirectory Source I could use that wouldn't require a build DropLocation.

To simplify, I want to copy files directly from a tfs Source control to a folder, using a Build Template, but that won't compile the files. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this problem. I created a new .xaml file and then the only item that I put in the sequence was "DownLoadFiles". Then I filled out the properties of the task and ran a "build" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

While the default .xaml build workflow for Team Foundation Build is indeed a compilation build it does not have to be. I usually recommend teams to at least have one compile and one deploy .xaml workflow.

1) The CompileMyStuff.xaml (DefaultBuildTemplate.xaml) should take my stuff from source control and do whatever is needed to create a Build Drop folder with my output. I may or may not need to actually compile before creating the drop, and it looks like you just want to copy to the drop location.

2) The DeployMyStuff.xaml should take a build number and deploy my code to an environment of my choice.

It looks like you want to skip the "Drop" and go state to deploy and while I would never recommend this you do have a "BuildDetail.BuildLocation" for teh local workspace where the build server has done a get of your code. You can just "CopyDirectory" from there to your server/host for the website.

If you are having a little trouble you could use the [Community Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/documentation) and fire up PowerShell to do your copy/deploy.